# Is it possible to iterate over a `const vector<int>`?

Tags: c++, std

Is it possible to iterate over a `const vector<int>`? Or, would this be undesirable anyway?

Given I have the function `getIntVector` which returns a `vector<int>` I can iterate over it with the following:

```
vector<int> vec = getIntVector();
vector<int>::iterator it;
for (it=vec.begin();it!=vec.end();++it) {}
```

But I can not do the following:

```
const vector<int> vec = getIntVector();
vector<int>::iterator it;
// complier throws error below
for (it=vec.begin();it!=vec.end();++it) {}
```

My thinking was that the vector would not be recreated by declaring it as a `const`....

Comment: `const_iterator`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) you need a [`vector<int>::const_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) to iterate through a "const" container

2) Your vector will still get copied; this may or may not be desireable. I like to return references...

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can you explain why it will still be copied, and by "I like to return references" do you mean return a pointer to the original vector? Thanks.

Comment: @Ross, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: @Ross whatever you do, don't return references to local variables.

Comment: I won't. The function returning the vector is an external library, so I was trying to optimise how I deal with a quick iteration. Any suggestions welcome, or if I am making a fuss out of nothing that would be good to know...

Answer (score 7):

If you're using C++11, you can use `auto`, and let the compiler infer the type from the initialization as:

```
for (auto it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) 
   //^^^^ compiler will infer the type using the initialization expression
```

In C++03, however, you have to use `const_iterator`.

Comment: Or just `for (int i : getIntVector())` if you don't care about `it` at all and just want a quick iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`vector<int>::const_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vector<int>::const_iterator`.